# How to hydrate vee-validate from the server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

Situation:

I have a form with an input which is stored with the `unique` constraint.
Following the documentation (https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/async-backend-validation.html) I know I can make an async validation in the client side without too much effort.

But also I want to make server side validations e.g. the `unique` validation, and if it fails, to "rehydrate" vee validate with the new failed validations.

I know I can do things like `this.$validator.errors.add(inputName, message[, rule])` (https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/406#issuecomment-290971863).

But it isn't quite what I'm looking for: (1) the message is required, even when I define the failed rule, e.g. the `unique` rule; (2) even when I define a rule in the new error, vee validate doesn't take it into account: if the `unique` rule fails because two users, at the same time, creates an element with the same value in the `unique` attribute, then then error is added to the last user, BUT if the value changes, that error isn't going to be cleared automatically.

Question:

Is it possible, with vee validate, to flag validation rules as failed, without setting the message by hand when it is stored in its dictionary, and without the step to clear the error by hand?

Thank you!

Comment: the first link you gave does not work

Comment: The domain does not exists anymore and the new documentation changed a lot since this 2 years. The internet archive doesn't has it either